# The alternative way for replacing NSCoding on swift

Tags: ios, swift

One common way to persist data on iOS is using archiving, and you need to conform to the NSCoding protocol when the persist data class is instanced. But I find there are many method under NSKeyedArchiver is deprecated, does it mean the NSCoding is not advised to be used in latest iOS version or a new way to replace it?

Comment: There are several non-deprecated methods. Just use those.

Comment: My best guess: NSCoding is not going away any soon. It is still good to use it in your apps. Deprecated methods will be cleaned-up in future Swift versions, but this doesn't mean that the whole classes will be deleted.